# What was Draco supposed to say?

Tags: harry-potter

One of the funniest improvised lines in *Harry Potter* was during the *Chamber of Secrets* when Harry and Ron drink Polyjuice potion to sneak into the Slytherin common room to spy on Draco to see if he was the heir of Slytherin. Draco asked Harry/Crabbe: "Why are you wearing glasses?" Harry says: "Oh, uh for reading..." Draco responds with: "I didn't know you could read."

Does anyone know what Draco was supposed to say?

Comment: if this is an accurate script - the entire bit was improvised it seems - so it's not a question of 'what was he supposed to say instead?' - it was just an added bit in between what was written (and also shot) -  http://nldslab.soe.ucsc.edu/charactercreator/film_corpus/film_20100519/all_imsdb_05_19_10/Harry-Potter-and-the-Chamber-of-Secrets.html

Comment: Is this in the movie or in the book?